# CRUD Repository findById() different return value

Tags: java, spring, crud

**In my SpringBoot applicatication I'm using CrudRepo.
I have found a problem with return value: Required != Found**

GitHub: https://github.com/einhar/WebTaskManager/tree/findById-problem

No matter about changing method return type from Task into Object -> IDE stopped show error, but then it could be problem due to validation of data type later on.

Do you know how to fix it? Any hint?

### CrudRepo

```
public interface TaskRepository extends CrudRepository<Task, Integer> {}
```

### Service

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class TaskService {

    @Autowired
    private final TaskRepository taskRepository;

    public TaskService(TaskRepository taskRepository) {
        this.taskRepository = taskRepository;
    }

    public List<Task> findAll() {
        List<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Task task : taskRepository.findAll()) {
                tasks.add(task);
        }
        return tasks; // Work properly :)
    }
    /* ... */
    public Task findTask(Integer id) {
        return taskRepository.findById(id); // Find:Task | Required: java.util.Optional :(
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to use Optional<Task>?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The findById method is return Optional, So you can get the task by get() method. You can choose the following 3 case
You will get an exception when Task not found:

```
public Task findTask(Integer id) {
    return taskRepository.findById(id).get();
}
```

You will get null when Task not found:

```
public Task findTask(Integer id) {
    return taskRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
}
```

You will get an empty new Task when Task not found:

```
public Task findTask(Integer id) {
    return taskRepository.findById(id).orElse(new Task());
}
```

Or just return the Optional Object

```
public Optional<Task> findTask(Integer id) {
    return taskRepository.findById(id);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've made some examples and got how it works.

Answer (score 0):

in your CrudRepo create a method:

```
Task getById(Integer id);
```

and then call this method in your TaskService and you should be ready to go:)

Answer (score 0):

I think no need to create getById(... id) method in Repository bean class because in SimpleJPARepository such method is already implemented. So you can directly call this method.
See Official spring document:-

```
/*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository#findById(java.io.Serializable)
     */
    public Optional<T> findById(ID id) {

        Assert.notNull(id, ID_MUST_NOT_BE_NULL);

        Class<T> domainType = getDomainClass();

        if (metadata == null) {
            return Optional.ofNullable(em.find(domainType, id));
        }

        LockModeType type = metadata.getLockModeType();

        Map<String, Object> hints = getQueryHints().withFetchGraphs(em).asMap();

        return Optional.ofNullable(type == null ? em.find(domainType, id, hints) : em.find(domainType, id, type, hints));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get an exception when Task not found, to solve this add an exception to your code
like this:

```
 public Task findTask(Integer id) {
    return taskRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(()-> new RuntimeException(String.format("Account %s not found",id)));
}
```