# Spring Data JPA findById() method returning null instead of Empty Optional

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, option-type

I have a method that is making use of Spring Data JPA's findById() method is supposed to return an Optional. However, in case the entity is not found by the specified id, it is returning **null** instead of an Empty Optional.

```
 public TicketEntity findTicket(String ticket) throws EntityNotFoundException {

    Optional<TicketEntity> op = ticketEntityRepository.findById(ticket);

    TicketEntity ticketEntity = op.orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("ticket with the id " + ticket + " not found in the system"));

    return ticketEntity;
}
```

While debugging, I found that the value of **op** is null.
This is the piece of code that is failing. I am using Spring Data JPA 2.0.8.RELEASE. Please help

Comment: look like means? The syntax?

Comment: @YCF_L code is generated by spring data jpa

Comment: findById() is a method defined by Spring-data-jpa. I have not defined this method

Comment: oops my bad @gagansingh sorry I thought the OP create it manually

Comment: have a look the [nullability docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.nullability.annotations)

Comment: Please provide a reproducable testcase and file a bug. This shouldn't happen.

Comment: Is this in a live system or while running a test with mocked dependencies.

Comment: @M.Deinum This is not a live system. I am trying to run tests with mocked dependencies

Comment: And `null` is the default response for a mock. You will have to tell the mock that it needs to return an `Optional.empty()`.

Comment: @M.Deinum You should post this comment as an answer because this is the root cause. I changed the mock to return Optional.empty() and it worked like a charm. Thanks a lot for your help. I truly appreciate that.

Comment: Assuming that you are using Mockito it should actually return an empty optional. Which spring boot and Mockito version are you using? See https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/1416#issuecomment-401153254

Comment: check this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49967692/5872337

Answer (score 4):

In a comment you state that this is in a test with mocked dependencies. The mocking takes Spring Data JPA out of the picture completely as it now is just a proxy implemented by a mock from [Mockito](http://site.mockito.org).

The default behavior for a mock is to return `null`.

> By default, for all methods that return a value, a mock will return either null, a primitive/primitive wrapper value, or an empty collection, as appropriate. For example 0 for an int/Integer and false for a boolean/Boolean.

As you are running with a mock you will need to instruct it to return an `Optional.empty()` else you will get `null`.

*NOTE:* You might want to create an improvement request for Mockito to default return `Optional.empty` in the case of an `Optional` return type.

Comment: How would you instruct it to do that? Given the example code line: Mockito.when(repository.findById(Mockito.any()).orElse(null)).thenReturn(myValue);

Answer (score 1):

What is the implementation of your Repository Class? The following repository and test case works for me.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class PersonRepoTest {

    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    @Test
    public void testFindById(){
        Optional<Person> byId = personRepository.findById(1);
        Assert.assertTrue(byId != null);
    }
}

public interface PersonRepository  extends CrudRepository<Person, Integer> {
}
```

Answer (score -4):

The line of code

Optional op = ticketEntityRepository.findById(ticket);

return list of result set if data exists in the system, otherwise it is obvious that it will return null instead of empty optional.
If you need an empty optional list you can twist it as follows

List op = ticketEntityRepository.findById(ticket).orElse(new ArrayList());

Comment: so the method findById is supposed to return the object or null, then why return optional? that is the question.